# Does Struts2 Application Run on Jboss5.0.0GA?

Tags: struts2, jboss5.x

Does Struts2 Application Run on Jboss5.0.0GA??

Getting the error in struts-default.xml file

Comment: What's the error?  More info is needed than this if we're to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes.  If yours doesn't, it means you've made an error.

Comment: I am getting the following error while running the sinmple struts application on jboss5.The same application is running perfectly fine with JBOSS4.0.5GA.




The error is as follows:
16:24:05,752 ERROR [[/Struts2HellowWorld]] Exception starting filter struts2
Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - [unknown location]

Comment: Check to see what changed with regard to Struts from JBOSS 4 to 5.  Believe the 2nd result - the fact that it's running "perfectly fine" on JBOSS 4 isn't applicable if you want to run on JBOSS 5.  I don't know what is different, but something is.  Check the JAR versions.  I'd also check the struts-default XSD or DTD and see if something is different there.  Maybe the namespaces have changed.